How can I get block range of Arbitrum blocks by batchSequenceNumber or lvl1BlockNumber?
Could someone explain please, if I know only "batchSequenceNumber", how can I receive the block range of lvl2 blocks that were included in the batch?
I really appreciate any help you can provide.
